# Antonym of prior to?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Given the following sentence, in the context of a video about flying a plane:

> The heading remained unchanged prior to 02:50

Reversing the meaning of this:

> The heading remained unchanged after 02:50

Is there another word you can use other than "after"?

<sub>Aside: this is possibly a bad example, since "after" isn't a bad fit in that sentence.</sub>

Comment: Could you please give an example where *after* is a poor fit so that people know what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what nuance of temporal meaning you are trying to convey.

I think "subsequent" is the best antonym for "prior"

Answer (score 2):

Post 
[post-
a prefix, meaning “behind,” “after,” “later,” “subsequent to,” “posterior to,” occurring originally in loanwords from Latin ( postscript  ), but now used freely in the formation of compound words ( post-Elizabethan; postfix; postgraduate; postorbital  ).](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/post)

Answer (score 1):

How about *posterior to*? That would be the most bureaucratese antonym to the bureaucratese *prior to*.

> As Theodore Bernstein once pointed out, one should feel free to use
>   *prior to* instead of *before* only if one is accustomed to using
>   *posterior to* for *after*.

Garner, *Modern American Usage*

Comment: I think the antonym of posterior is anterior.

Answer (score 1):

How about "past?"

> The heading remained unchanged past 02:50.

[If the situation remains unchanged past 2014 or 2015...](http://www.seafood.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fFeaturedStory%2f909991%2fStory.aspx%3fstory%3d916298%26topic%3d58465&story=916298&topic=58465)

Answer (score 1):

*subsequent (to), posterior (to),* or just *after* are the best choices, or rephrase to use a different pair of antonyms.

The etymological antonym of *prior* is *[ulterior](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ulterior)* (from Latin), and it used to be used as such, but this is now rare to non-existent. Compare *primate/ultimate* for “first/last”, and you also hear echos of this is in *pro-*/*proto-* (Ancient Greek) vs. *ultra-* (Latin).

Your choices are either to use another antonym (which doesn’t pair as well), or change both words. *before/after*, *(up) to/from*, and *earlier than/later than* are Germanic, while *precedent (to)/subsequent (to)*, *anterior (to)/posterior (to)* are Latinate, but in these pairs the term meaning “before” is very formal.